# Creating pandas dataframe from a csv file with each line having information in `column:value` form with extraneous information

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

I have an empty dataframe with columns `A`, `B`, and `G`

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['A','B','E'])
```

I have a file `file.csv` in the following form. Here each line has text in the form of `column:value`. The `value` can have space inside it like `I am`. For each line I am only interested in values corresponding to `column` name `A`, `B`, and `G`. In case any of these are missing in a line, I want to put `NA` for that particular column for the row I am adding in the dataframe.

```
A:rice , B:mango , C:water , D:lemon , E:I am
A:wheat , C:water , D:orange , E:I am not
A:rice , B:apple , C:coke , D:mellon
```

I want the following dataframe at the end

```
      A          B          E
0     rice     mango      I am
1     wheat     NA        I am not
2     rice     apple       NA
```

Note that for the second line in the text file, I do not have any value for `B`, so I put `NA` for that column in the corresponding row in the dataframe. Same scenario for column `E` for the third row.

What is a clean way to do this?

Comment: how many rows have your csv ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a quick answer, try:

```
from functools import reduce


(pd.read_csv('file.csv', header=None, sep=',')
    .apply(lambda row: pd.Series(reduce(lambda x,y: {**x, **y}, row.dropna().str.split(':').apply(lambda x: {x[0]:x[1]}))), 
    axis=1)
)
```

Or to make it more legible:

```
from functools import reduce

def cell_to_dictionary(cell):
    '''Converts "A:val" to {"A":"val"}'''
    key,val = cell.split(':')
    return {key:val}

(pd.read_csv('file.csv', header=None, sep=',')
  .apply(lambda row: reduce(lambda x,y: {**x, **y}, row.dropna().apply(cell_to_dictionary)), axis=1)
  .apply(pd.Series)
)
```

For an even neater answer:

```
from functools import reduce

def cell_to_dictionary(cell):
    '''Converts "A:val" to {"A":"val"}'''
    key,val = cell.split(':')
    return {key:val}

(pd.read_csv('file.csv', header=None, sep=',')
    .apply(lambda row: row.dropna().to_list(), axis=1)
    .apply(lambda x: [cell_to_dictionary(val) for val in x])
    .apply(lambda x: reduce(lambda a,b: {**a, **b}, x))
    .apply(pd.Series)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use apply func to create new expected columns.

Example:

```
Lt=["A:test1","B:test2","A:test3"]
df=pd.DataFrame(columns=["A"])
# create new column by apply func
df["AA"]=df["A"].apply(lambda x:x.split(":")[1] if x.split(":")[0]=="A" else np.nan )
```

output:

```
     A       AA
0   A:test1  test1
1   B:test2  NaN
2   A:test3  test3
```

Comment: the result is empty

Comment: Tired  in my jupyter notebook and gained the results what I posted here. Could you please show your code?

Answer (score 0):

```
 import pandas as pd
    import itertools
    flatten = itertools.chain.from_iterable
    import numpy as np

    df = pd.read_csv(df,header=None,sep='[,|:]') # Reading your data file using sep = [,|:], This will create seperate columns for column headers
    df_col =  df.iloc[::2, ::2] # Selecting all the column names columns, that is even columns
    df = df.drop(df[df.columns[::2]].columns, axis = 1) # Dropping all the column names columns

    col_names = []
    for col in df_col:
    """This will get the array list of column names"""
        (col_names.append (df_col[col].dropna().unique()))
    df.columns = list(flatten(col_names)) # Assigning the column names back
```

I am pretty much new to Python so this may not be the optimized way, but see if this helps you.

```
Normal Import: (without using the sep=[,|:])

       0      1       2       3          4
0   A:rice  B:mango C:water  D:lemon    E:I am
1   A:wheat C:water D:orange E:I am not NaN
2   A:rice  B:apple C:coke   D:mellon   NaN


Using 'Sep': (with sep = [:|,])

        0    1      2     3     4     5     6     7       8     9
    0   A   rice    B   mango   C   water   D   lemon     E     I am
    1   A   wheat   C   water   D   orange  E   I am not  None  None
    2   A   rice    B   apple   C   coke    D   mellon    None  None

After executing the code:

            A         B       C       D        E
        0   rice    mango   water   lemon     I am
        1   wheat   water   orange  I am not  None
        2   rice    apple   coke    mellon    None
```